# Intel Virtualization hidden in BIOS

Tags: cpu, bios, virtualization, intel

I am trying to enable virtualization on my Debian system. The command

```
sudo modprobe kvm-intel
```

fails with `Operation not supported` error.

- Processor: Intel Xeon E31260L
- Motherboard: Intel Serverboard S1200BTL

The [intel specification](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/52275/intel-xeon-processor-e31260l-8m-cache-2-40-ghz/specifications.html) for my processor tells that virtualization **is supported**:

[image: intel-cpu-specification-screenshot]

## Here are the BIOS screenshots:

### Main

[image]

### Advanced

[image]

### Advanced > Processor Configuration

[image: bios-proc-config-screenshot]

### Security

[image]

### Server Management

[image]

As you can see, there is nothing for "Intel Virtualization" "VT-d" "VT-x" or anything similar.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The option could be anywhere. I’ve seen it under “Security”.

Comment: indeed, many firmwares treat virtualization extensoins as a "security" feature.

Comment: @DanielB nothing there either. Attached screenshots

Comment: @FrankThomas nothing there either. Attached screenshots

Comment: @FrankThomas please see screenshot at page 29 here https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/g16972005_s1200bt_sg.pdf . Don't you think it proves that mobo supports virtualization?

Comment: @Rockrid3r in theory the motherboard supports it, but for whatever reason is not showing it. Maybe the firmware does not fully recognise your processor. Checking for firmware updates might be an option.

Comment: ok, I do see that the board implements the C204 chipset, which does list VT-d support, even if the mobo on ark doesn't. https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52804/intel-c204-chipset.html anyway yes I'd look for a firmware update.